# Xcode14.2/Mac:Vecture/Bundle React Native code and images

Tags: react-native

The build went through and I can upload to TestFlight, but I can't upload static images.
I don't know what is wrong and I need help.

Xcode14.2
Mac:Vecture（M2）
cocoapods:1.12.1
react-native-cli: 2.0.1
react-native: 0.61.4

I tried this commands.
for debug: npx react-native bundle --entry-file index.js --platform ios --dev true --bundle-output ios/main.jsbundle

and for release: npx react-native bundle --entry-file index.js --platform ios --dev false --bundle-output ios/main.jsbundle